# Django CSRF verification failed on post method

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I dont understand this one...

the token is in the template and the 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' is define in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from ezmapping.models import *
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

def setMapOptions(request):
    ezMapFormSet = modelformset_factory(ezMap, fields=('map_name', 'zoom_level', 'center_lat', 'center_long', 'map_width', 'map_height'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ezMapFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()

    else:
        formset = ezMapFormSet(queryset=ezMap.objects.filter(map_name ='first test'))
    return render_to_response("ezmapping/manage_mapOptions.html", {'formset': formset,})
```

template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Manage Map Options</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Define map options</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form.as_p }} 
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `RequestContext` to use the CSRF tags.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

```
context = RequestContext(request, {
        'foo': 'bar',
    })

# or

render_to_response('foo.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

`RequestContext` takes the request object and loads all kinds of variables automatically, including CSRF.

Comment: Indeed.. personally, I've never used these in a whole year I bet since going to CBVs..